# Google Visualization Line Chart using Google Sheet Code Example

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I'm looking for sample code for using a Google Sheet as the source data and make a fairly simple line chart using Google Visualization.

I noticed that the new Google Sheets don't include a script in the "Share Chart" function, they offer a IFRAME and the width/height doesn't work.  So, I'm looking to do it with Google Visualizations.

[Here is my sample chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MXilv-uhEAUxDzVB7qVCCmQYqkmWvqqaBOXeBsS04k/embed/oimg?id=14MXilv-uhEAUxDzVB7qVCCmQYqkmWvqqaBOXeBsS04k&oid=784089984&zx=4724tjiwvic4).

Thank you for the help.

Edited...

[Here is my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MXilv-uhEAUxDzVB7qVCCmQYqkmWvqqaBOXeBsS04k/edit?usp=sharing).

Here is my HTML file.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawChart() {
            var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=14MXilv-uhEAUxDzVB7qVCCmQYqkmWvqqaBOXeBsS04k&gid=0');
            query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E');
            query.send(function (response) {
                if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }

                var data = response.getDataTable();

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('linechart'));
                chart.draw(data, {
                    height: 400,
                    width: 600
                });
            });
        }
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['corechart'],
            callback: drawChart
        });
    </script>

    <title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="linechart"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

It doesn't draw.  I've tried various selection in the spreadsheet like avoiding column A, no go.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code to get you started:

```
function drawChart() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key={spreadsheet key}&gid=0');
    query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C');
    query.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data = response.getDataTable();

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            height: 400,
            width: 600
        });
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

You would need to replace the `{spreadsheet key}` in the URL with your own spreadsheet key (eg: `'http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=1234567890&gid=0'`) and change the query to select the appropriate columns from your spreadsheet.

In your page's HTML, you need to have a container div that matches the ID used when creating the chart (`'chart_div'` in this case):

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried 100 different combinations between last night and this morning.  There really aren't any well documented examples around for newbies.  I found some Google documentation on how to select a range but they don't actually show you how to construct the URL exactly.  I've tried things like commenting out the query line in the function and adding &range=A1:D4 but I still can't get anything to draw.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong.  I tried forking one of your examples on JSFiddle with my sheet and it doesn't draw?  http://jsfiddle.net/davelalande/DQQcS/2/

Comment: I've figured out my initial problem.  My sheet was on the new Google Sheets and it's not working.  I built a test sheet on my personal account which is still using the old sheets and it draws.  I don't mind building these charts in my personal account and I'm sure I'll need more help asgallant if you'd be kind enough to field some questions for me.  Thanks for the JSFiddle BTW.

Comment: Here is my Google Sheet.  https://docs.google.com/a/davelalande.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdHBELWZoZHRaQTl5VXdRa3JLTzByUlE&usp=drive_web#gid=1

The label date label turns on as we receive and enter data.  I think this must me effecting my chart code because it's not drawing now when I go back to this technique. I would like to get this thing to add months of data as we get them.

Comment: What do you mean by "date label turns on as we receive and enter data"?  Can you update the jsfiddle with your new spreadsheets?

Comment: I was looking at something along these lines http://jsfiddle.net/5qxbS/ and probably copy/paste some code.  I need something very similar to this "but" fed with a Google sheet so that the department Directors can enter data as it comes in.

Comment: You had a couple of syntax errors that needed to be cleaned up.  Is this what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DQQcS/14/

Comment: Thank you asgallant.  You're the best.  I post the solution on Github for others to learn from.  Thanks again.